# How to group separately by multiple columns in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, group-by

I know that you can use the GROUP BY keyword to group by multiple columns, but I don't know how to group by separate groups in one query:

```
Table: Humans

 id | name | surname  | year  |
----|------|----------|-------|
 1  | Egor | Krid     |  14   |
 2  | Dima | Maxnin   |  12   |
 3  | Ivan | Krid     |  12   |
 4  | Egor | Petrenko |  12   |
```

Using only GROUP BY I get this:

```
SELECT name, surname, year, count(*) FROM Humans
GROUP BY name, surname, year

-----------------------------------------------
Table: Humans

 name | surname  | year  | count
------|----------|-------|-------
 Egor | Krid     |  14   | 1
 Egor | Petrenko |  12   | 1
 Dima | Maxnin   |  12   | 1
 Ivan | Krid     |  12   | 1
```

But this is the result I want to get:

```
Table: Humans

 name | surname  | year  | count
------|----------|-------|-------
 Dima |          |       | 1
 Egor |          |       | 2
 Ivan |          |       | 1
      | Krid     |       | 2
      | Maxnin   |       | 1
      | Petrenko |       | 1
      |          | 12    | 3
      |          | 14    | 1
```

As you can see, the columns are grouped into separate groups, and the last column shows the number of them. I assume that you will need to add this to the query: `ORDER BY "name", "surname", "year"`. Can someone explain what to use for this in PostgreSQL?

Comment: Why do you want this output?

Comment: So that later my program would make statistics, and the logic itself would be implemented via PostgreSQL. It's just that I'm currently studying PostgreSQL :)

Comment: I view your expected output as really being a handful of separate aggregation queries.  Just run the aggregations separately and make the results available.  I doubt you really need this exact output for any practical purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what [grouping sets()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-GROUPING-SETS) are for:

```
SELECT name, surname, year, count(*) 
FROM Humans
GROUP BY grouping sets( (name), (surname), (year) )
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=b57f0b400c11f036ffaa23b79c949538)

Answer (score 1):

Try this ([Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tVUrRQtCRKmDcdkpy8tSxz/0))

```
select name,'' as surname, count(*)
from humans
group by name

union

select '',surname, count(*)
from humans
group by surname
order by 2,1;
```